# Identify an object currently selected in the game

Tags: c++, 2d, sdl, isometric

I am making a 2D isometric game that uses the mouse. When I left click on an object, this object should be selected, but how do I determine what object that's currently selected and show a halo around it?

My objects are stored in a list of game objects as `std::vector<Game_Object *> Object_Game`. I am using the SDL library with C++. I did some research on Google but only found articles about Unity. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you making a 2D- or a 3D game?

Comment: I am making a 2d game, it is type “isometric”.

Comment: If your objects are inside a `vector`, can't you iterate through it and manually make collisions ?

Comment: Is your game tile-based? If so, you could find whatever isometric tile the mouse is pointing at and then determine whatever character / object is at that position. If not, you could always use the same technique by using a quadtree to keep track of characters / objects in your game and transform the isometric position to a position in the quadtree and find objects / characters at that position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use-case is two-fold:

1. Projecting your 2d mouse coordinates to 3d world coordinates, to create a ray.
2. Performing collision detection on the new coordinates, compared to your game objects.

**NDC to 3D world coordinates**

To do this, you need your view and projection transform matrices:

```
mat4 view = lookat(camPos, camPos+camDir, vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
// For 3D
mat4 projection = perspective(fovAngle, aspectRatio, znear, zfar);
//for 2D
mat4 projection = ortho(0, width, height, 0);
```

combine these matrices using affine transformations:

```
mat4 worldToScreen = projection * view;
```

then invert them:

```
mat4 screenToWorld = inverse(worldToScreen);
```

Now, we take our mouse coordinates, and transform into world coordinates:

```
vec3 worldMouse = screenToWorld * vec4(mouseX,mouseY,-1.0f,1.0f);
```

Then finally we create our ray:

```
vec3 ray = normalize(worldMouse - camPos);
```

**Collision Detection**

Now, we can iterate through a vector of game objects, to determine which one has been clicked on:

```
gameObject *selectedObject; = nullptr;
for (auto &gameobject: gameObjects)
{
    if (gameobject.collide(ray))
    {
        selectedObject = gameobject;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you can have some rendering code that draws a halo on the ground at the targeted object position:

```
void render()
{
    if (selectedObject != nullptr)
    {
        selectedHalo.drawAt(selectedObject->getPosition());
    }
    // then draw your game objects as normal.
}
```

This technique is known as "3D picking". There are plenty of more detailed tutorials available, but I covered the basic gist of it.

Comment: This is what you'd do in 3D but the original poster indicated this is a 2D game. Can you recommend how to construct the corresponding matrices for a 2D isometric game?

Comment: @amitp The principle still stands for a 2d game: change the mouse coordinates from NDC space to world space, then perform collision detection. Also, isometric is not 2D, it is usually defined as 2.5D. That being said, I will extend my answer appropriately.